# Google Charts: how style a cell with literal string

Tags: javascript, css, google-visualization

I have a google table chart and initialize my DataTable with JavaScript literal object syntax.
I want color the text of a specific cell so i do:

```
{"v":"OK", "p":'style: "color:#006600;"'}
```

But the text OK doesn't have the style.

I setthe the allowHtml option to true.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the correct sintax:

```
"p":{"style": "color:#006600;"}
```

You can view it working here : http://jsfiddle.net/g36g4mx7/